# Switch quickly between sets of layers in eagle

Tags: eaglecad, efficiency

Is there a way in eagle to quickly switch between sets of layers? e.g. all top layers, all bottom layers, both top and bottom.

Currently, when I want to see only the top layers, I have to click / unselect, Bottom, bPlace, bOrigins, bNames, bValues, bCream, bDocu.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you aware of layer presets?

[image]

Select the layers you need for the current view and then click and hold the layer button to create a new preset.

Repeat for the common layer configurations you need. Something like "Top routing", "Bottom routing", "Mechanical", "Placement" and so on.